# Meteor MongoDB Server Aggregation into new Collection

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I'm currently experimenting with a test collection on a LAN-accessible MongoDB server and data in a Meteor (v1.6) application. View layer of choice is React and right now I'm using the createContainer to bind the subscriptions to props.

The data that gets put in the MongoDB storage is updated on a daily basis and consists of a big set of data from several SQL databases, netting up to about 60000 lines of JSON per day. The data has been ever-so-slightly reshaped to be turned into a usable format whilst remaining as RAW as I'd like it to be.

The working solution right now is fetching all this data and doing further manipulations client-side to prepare the data for visualization. The issue should seem obvious: each client is fetching a set of documents that grows every day and repeats a lot of work on earlier entries before being ready to display. I want to do this manipulation on the server, through MongoDB's Aggregation Framework.

My initial idea is to do the aggregations on the server and to create new Collections containing smaller, more specific datasets without compromising the RAWness of the original Collection. That would mean the "reduced" Collections can still be reactive, as I've been able to confirm through testing in a Remote Desktop, subscribing to an aggregated Collection which I can update through Robo3T.

I don't know if this would be ideal. As far as storage goes, there's plenty of room for the extra Collections. But I have no idea how to set up an automated aggregation script on said server. And regarding Meteor, I've tried using `meteorhacks:aggregate` and `jcbernack:reactive-aggregate` but couldn't figure out how to deal with either one of them. If anyone is dealing, or has dealt with, something similar; I'd love to hear ideas / suggestions.

Comment: I have used cron jobs and mongos-mapReduce to crunch data into new collection. Worked like a charm.

Comment: A CRON job, thanks! Searching on that term has helped. Looks like I'm going to have to do something with the Task Scheduler in Windows Server to get the desired outcome. I'll mess around with it a bit and will get back with any results I get.

Comment: You could ensure indexes are set to make the aggregations fast and just use server-side methods to provide aggregated data sets instead of returning all the rows from the collections. Once that becomes too slow or too server intensive for the server I'd start to look into new collections.There are a couple of `cron` modules out there so you could trigger these operations from your server side code if you want.

Comment: Seems like it's getting somewhere. Made a scheduled task and used the aggregation file to process the data. The process starts successfully and loads the mongo.exe shell. The test collection gets filled with new data, verified with both Robo3T and the Meteor app displaying the new set of props. Next week I'll test with a more intricate JSON structure of data.

Comment: @Hans it _seems_ that ^ will become my preferred solution as that'd be more convenient for my co-workers when I leave. I'm running an internship and this server-side stuff is completely new to me. Already stoked about how this is shaping up.

Comment: If you want to manage your cron jobs with meteor directly have a look at the `synced-cron` atmosphere package. Very convenient.